# Apache configuration limits for PHP FTP

Tags: php, apache, ftp

I've got a PHP script, launched via an AJAX POST request, which does the following actions :

1. `ftp_get` from server A to the local server
2. `ftp_put` from the local server to server B
3. `ftp_put` from the local server to server A
4. `ftp_delete` on server A

That script failed today, but didn't send back an HTTP error (such as error 500). The file that was being treated was quite large (around 220 MB), but I need my system to be able to work with even bigger files than that.

Is there an Apache configuration value (such as `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size`) which could have caused the interruption? In short, what are the potentially blocking Apache configuration values used by a PHP script which does FTP actions?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there are any FTP-specific limits.

But an overall PHP [`max_execution_time`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) can be the culprit.

Apache also can have its own limit. See [Does Apache set a max execution time of its own?](https://serverfault.com/q/348707/168875).

Comment: I already set the `max_execution_time` to 7200, which is more than enough since the script failed after 4 or 5 minutes.